# How to add another main item on Toolbar (SupportActionBar)?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

i want to add another one main item icon(the left one from title, hamburger icon) at Toolbar (SupportActionBar).
I want to hide it in one case and show in another (for back arrow in one case, and change it to hamburger icon in another). So is there a way to do so?

And i want it as menu item, not just change the icon at item. I want to use it this way

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.hamburger:
            setActionBarMenu();
            return true;

        case android.R.id.back:
            setActionBarMenu();
            return true;}}
```